# Postgres not converting from a java boolean to numeric data column automatically?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, spring-data-jpa, sqldatatypes

I have an Oracle database that is currently being migrated to an AWS Aurora Postgres database. As part of this I have had to update some of the datatypes in our sql files for creating tables e.g. changing `NUMBER` to `NUMERIC` etc. It has been going well but I am now coming across the following error when trying to insert some data into a table using spring data/JPA

```
ERROR: column "some_table_column" is of type numeric but expression is of type boolean
```

I can identify the issue is probably that the java class defines this column like

```
@Column(name = "SOME_TABLE_COLUMN", nullable = false)
private boolean someTableColumn;
```

while the sql file defines it like

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE 
(    
SOME_TABLE_COLUMN NUMERIC(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
etc..
```

Don't ask why it has been defined like this, I didn't write this code, I've just inherited it. But this has not been an issue ever with the Oracle database, and I'm only seeing the error now when running against Postgres. Does Oracle do some sort of implict conversion behind the scene that Postgres doesn't do? Is there a way I can resolve this without having to migrate the column to a boolean datatype?

Comment: Can you change that numeric field to an integer? That would solve your problem. If not, you can create a custom cast that takes care of the casting from numeric to boolean

Comment: It depends on whether you want the value in Postgres to be `boolean` or not. Note: I am not a Java programmer. If you want to end up as numeric then  it would seem changing this; `private boolean someTableColumn;` to something like `private numeric someTableColumn;` or whatever the Java numeric equivalent type is. Otherwise as @FrankHeikens said a `CAST` is in order. In Postgres you can do: `select 't'::bool::int::numeric; 1; select 'f'::bool::int::numeric; 0`.

Comment: Oracle has no boolean data type (that can be used for a column's data type), so maybe the Oracle JDBC driver does this mapping automatically. Postgres does have a proper boolean data type, so the driver most likely doesn't care about converting a number to a boolean.

Comment: Migrate the `NUMBER` to a `boolean` instead, and the problem will go away.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I unfortunately can't convert the type of the java object, it will need to be done at the database level. Is the example you provided how you implement a `CAST`? I have tried it out but I get the following error `syntax error at or near "1"`. Can you advise if i'm doing it correclty?

Comment: As @LaurenzAlbe said make `SOME_TABLE_COLUMN NUMERIC(1)` be `SOME_TABLE_COLUMN BOOLEAN`

Comment: I have done that, but it doesn't solve my problem. So the java object type is still a `boolean` and now the database column is also a `BOOLEAN`, but when I make a query like `jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_TABLE_COLUMN=1)` it just gives the error  `ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer`. I can tell it's failing because it's querying a boolean column with an int value `1`, but I need it to cast this `1` to a `t` somehow, and I can't do this in the query itself, because it needs to be backwards compatible with Oracle.

Comment: In Postgres, `... WHERE SOME_TABLE_COLUMN=1::boolean;` or more standard method `where column2 = CAST(1 AS boolean);`.

Comment: Is there no way to this without altering the query itself i.e. to configure postgres to do it automatically? I ask this because if I have to manually update all the queries in the code, then that is honestly not feasible IMO. There are simply too many places that would require the change, and I would have to not only add new sql, but also tons of `if` conditions to determine which database is running and then use the correct sql. Surely there must be a way I can configure postgres to do this for me?

Comment: Assuming you have the Postgres column as a boolean type. Then try: `select * from pg_cast where castsource = 'integer'::regtype and casttarget = 'bool'::regtype;` it should return a row. Then `update pg_cast set castcontext = 'i' where castsource = 'integer'::regtype and casttarget = 'bool'::regtype;`. This converts the integer --> boolean cast to implicit. This is not a good thing to do as it messing with a system table and will not survive version upgrades. Also things like `where 3` will evaluate to true. You have been warned.

Comment: Hmm, just realized you are on AWS. You may not be able to work with the system tables.