# How to query a boolean column using an integer with Postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I post a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576150/) previously, but have opened another question to be more specific as the previous one gave me a solution but I have now encountered another problem.

We have an existing Oracle database that had boolean columns defined like so

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE 
(    
SOME_TABLE_COLUMN NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
etc..
```

And with the corresponding java field defined like `private boolean someTableColumn;` I've come to understand this is because Oracle does not have a Boolean datatype, but under the hood does the conversion from boolean to integer when inserting data, and the reverse when retriving data.

This has caused an issue when I have been working on migrating our database from Oracle to Postgres. Thanks to answers on my previous question, I have migrated the column type from `NUMBER(1)` to `BOOLEAN`. This has solved the issue with inserting data. However, our codebase uses `JDBCTemplate` and we unfortunately have hundereds of hardcoded queries in the code that make queries like `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TABLE_COLUMN=1`.

When these run against the Postgres DB, I get the following error `ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer`. We have a requirement to have backwards compatability with Oracle, so I can't simply update these queries to replace `1` and `0` with `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively.

Is there a way I can configure Postgres so it can do a conversion behind the scenes to resolve this? I have looked at casts but I don't really understand the documentation and the examples given don't seem to match my use case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use '0' and '1' instead of 0 and 1 in your requests ?
I used to work on apps compliant with both Oracle and Postgresql using this syntax. Apps were using JPA but can say with certainty that we were also using this syntax with nativeQuery = true.

Note: I would have posted this as a comment but I don't have the required reputation to do so, hence the post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Duh! Brain Freeze. On later thought there is a way to get this conversion in both directions. Process via a **View**.
Steps:

1. Rename your table.
2. Create a view having the same name as the old table. In this view
   translate the boolean column to the appropriate integer.
3. Create an trigger function and an [instead of](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) trigger on the view for insert/update dml. In the trigger function translate the column value to boolean as appropriate.

See [revised demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0e85e84829e410cc8c1f2e54a7448661).

```
alter table testb rename to testb_tab; 

create or replace view testb (id, name, is_ok) 
as 
select i,
     , name
     , is_ok::int 
  from testb_tab; 
 
  
create or replace 
function testb_act_dml()      
 returns trigger 
 language plpgsql 
as $$ 
begin
    if tg_op = 'INSERT' then 
        insert into testb_tab(name,is_ok) 
          values (new.name, new.is_ok::boolean) ; 
    else 
        update testb_tab
          set name = new.name 
            , is_ok = new.is_ok::boolean 
        where id = old.id; 
    end if;
   
    return new; 
end;
$$; 
     
create trigger  testb_biuri   -- before insert update row instead of 
       instead of insert or update on testb
       for each row execute function testb_act_dml();
```

Finally, there is another option which probably has the lease work. Do not change the column description to Boolean. Either leave it as an integer or define it as a smallint. Either way a check constraint may come in useful. So something along the line of:

```
create table tests( id int generated always as identity primary key
                  , name   text
                  , is_ok  smallint
                  , constraint is_ok_ck 
                               check ( is_ok in (0,1) or is_ok is null)
                  );
```

---

This is one of the issues I have with the concept of "database independence". It simply does not exist. Vendors implementation often simply vary too much. In this case Postures to the rescue, perhaps but also perhaps extreme: create you own *create your own operators*. Proceed with caution:

```
-- function to compare boolean = integer 
create or replace 
function"__bool=int"( b boolean, i int) 
   returns boolean
  language sql
as $$
    select (b=i::boolean);
$$;  

-- create the Operator for boolean = integer
create operator = (
       leftarg = boolean
     , rightarg = int
     , function =  "__bool=int"
    , commutator = =
);
```

The above will not allow your code: `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TABLE_COLUMN=1` (see demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a859f09291b93a6b77625ecd4cda3e3e)).  
However, this road may lead to unexpected twists, and lots of function/operator pairs. For example the above does not support `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TABLE_COLUMN<>1`. That requires another function/operator combination. Further I do not see a retrieval function that converts a boolean back to an integer. If you follow this path be sure to massively test your boolean-to-integer (integer-to-boolean) operations. It may just be better to just byte the bullet and updated those **few** queries (you did say hundreds not thousands) as @mlogario suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I'll be honest that I don't fully understand all of it, but I will spend some time looking into it to understand it. I do have question about your second solution using constraints though - I don't think this will solve the problem? Because the type in java will still be a boolean and the database type an integer, so I suspect I'll get the same error where postgres can't convert from one type to the other. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you meant by your suggestion?

Comment: And also just to clarify, for your view solution, I take it I will need to create a view and the two trigger functions for all the tables this affects? (It will probably be between 10-20 tables). Or can I reuse any of them?

Comment: In Postures boolean variables/columns will have 1 of 3 possible values: true, fa,se, and null.  The constraint were for a solution keeping the column a integer type but restricted to just the corresponding 3 values: 1, 0, and null.

Comment: As for the View solution, Yes you will need the view and trigger for each table.  (And, anticipating, NO you cannot pass the table name as a parameter).  The big issue you have is just this  Your main problem is the idea of maintaining backward comparability to Oracle (or any other RDBMS, even perhaps different Postgres version). What are you going to do with Oracle collections  (do not exist in Postgres) or Postgres arrays (do not exist in Oracle). Sometimes implementation of essentially the same thing but where a different syntax is used.

Comment: I don't think adding the constraint, even if I kept the column as an integer would resolve the problem though, right? Because the core problem is the database column is an `integer` and the java type is `boolean` and postgres can't implicitly do a conversion between the two. So even if I limit the options to 1,0 or null, they will not match the expected values of t,f, or null. Please correct me if I'm wrong in this assumption.

Comment: The constraint is not for resolving. It merely serves to limit the **known** values to the representation of boolean. But you are correct it does not translate true, false to 0,1 respectively.  Without the constraint what would 42 mean.